# Unable to locate FromStream in Image class

Tags: c#, httpresponse, http-request

I have the following code:

```
Image tmpimg = null;
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
return Image.FromStream(stream);
```

On the last line when I type in `Image.`, `FromStream` isn't in the list. What can I do?

Comment: `I´ve got a problem with the found suggestions`. What is that problem?

Comment: Read the question. The problem is that FromStream can´t be found

Comment: The `FromStream` issue is clear. What was not clear was what deficiencies there were in other answers (or that this was it).

Comment: When I googled that or read the questions "Download Image from url" always `FromStream` is used. When I try it, it isn´t found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need `using System.Drawing;`.

Comment: Ok, I had the wrong using. I will accept your answer in 6 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Also you need to close/dispose the http response. Failing to do so leaves the http connection open and trying to make multiple requests to the same server will end up failing.

Answer (score 28):

More detailed out example with using and the namespaces needed.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

public static Image GetImageFromUrl(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        
            using (HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    return Image.FromStream(stream);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
`Image image1 = GetImageFromUrl("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Panda_Cub_from_Wolong,_Sichuan,_China.JPG");  
                                     //do something with your image`

Comment: Use `var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);` to avoid casting.

Answer (score 12):

try this one:

```
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;

    public static Image GetImageFromUrl(string url)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            return ByteArrayToImage(webClient.DownloadData(url));
        }
    }

    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great point on the byteArray!!  I am actually going to need this next week!! Perfect timing.

Answer (score 3):

btw, you also need to add reference to System.Drawing.dll, only adding using System.Drawing is not enough.