# How to pass a URI image path to FileInfo class?

Tags: c#, image

I have the below program that converts an image to byte array

```
public byte[] ReadImageFile(string imageLocation)
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(imageLocation);
            long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
            return imageData;
        }
```

If I pass the value as `"D:\\ENSource\\1.png"`, it works properly.

But If I send the value as "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PShuQ.png" it throws exception

> URI formats are not supported

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use e.g. the `WebClient` class to download the image from an URI location.

Comment: You can't. **URI formats are not supported.** If you want to load an image over the internet, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091997/best-way-image-url-to-drawing-image?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileInfo` and `FileStream` work with local files, there is no way to "pass Uri" to either of them.

To handle Uri you can either:

- map server to local drive (i.e. if server supports WebDAV).
- use Http related classes (like `HttpClient`, `WebClient`) to download file from server and get bytes. I.e. [Image to byte array from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599686/image-to-byte-array-from-a-url).

Comment: thanks Alexei... var webClient = new WebClient();
                byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://i.stack.imgur.com/PShuQ.png");

Answer (score 1):

***Edit!***
*Please see @Alexei's response.
He tossed in a much better (read: simpler) solution that uses webclient.
I'm leaving the response here in case someone wants to see a more "verbose" example of querying a web server.*

I just gave Alexei an up tick (he's quite right), but just to fill this in  . . .

Your communicating with a web server, not a file system.
As a result, you will need to "request" the data from the server manually, and then pass the resulting stream.

Please see the following code snippet . . .
http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Download-Image-from-URL.html